# Please check my solution, inverse semigroups.

Tags: semigroups, inverse-semigroups

> > Let $x$ and $y$ be elements of an inverse semigroup $S$. Then the following are equivalent:
> >
> > (1) $xy^{-1}x = x$
> >
> > (2) $x^{-1}yx^{-1}=x^{-1}$

I'm not sure in my solution, please check it for me.

For implication $(1) \Rightarrow (2)$, let $a,b \in S$ such that $ab^{-1}a=a$. Then we have $a^{-1}(b)a^{-1}=(a^{-1}ba^{-1})ba^{-1}=a^{-1}ba^{-1}= a^{-1}$. And for $(2) \Rightarrow (1)$ is similarly.

Comment: Why $(a^{-1}ba^{-1})ba^{-1}=a^{-1}ba^{-1}= a^{-1}$?

Comment: I think $a^{-1}ba^{-1} = a^{-1}(b^{-1})^{-1}a^{-1} = a^{-1}$.

Comment: You use the identity what you should preove.

Answer (score 3):

Let $xy^{-1}x = x$. To prove (2) you should use the identity $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$. Then
$$
x^{-1}=(xy^{-1}x)^{-1}=x^{-1}yx^{-1}
$$

Comment: Is $(aa^{-1})^{-1}=aa^{-1}$ ?

Comment: Yes, of course.